# Laravel Lumen Queue Failure with queue:work but not queue:listen

Tags: php, laravel, queue, lumen

I have an issue where I have a command that inserts jobs into a DB queue. I have a service "supervisor" basically running artisan queue:work continuesily (I should also mention I have a once per min cron job running artisan schedule:run). If I just run this command and let the supervisor pick up when the queued job should run I get this exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method App\Services\MiddlewareApi::get_lowest_active_customer_number_by_email() in /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.com/httpdocs/my-app/app/Jobs/UpdateBadCustomerNumbersJob.php:48
```

(I have checked and that class does indeed have that method)

but when I run php artisan queue:listen right after I run the command that calls the UpdateBadCustomerNumberJob.php things seem to function correctly. Should I make some sort of adjustment to my supervisor? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this issue was called because the queue wasn't picking up the new code changes I had deployed. This issue was solved by running queue:restart and rebooting the Supervisor.